# How to plot multiple csv files on the same plot?

Tags: python, csv, plotly

i have 8 csv files the have the same x,y axis with different values. i would like to plot them all on the same plot to compare between them.
this is a snap from a ploty code

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

 df = pd.read_csv("file1.csv")
 df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')
 fig = px.line(df, x = 'values', y = 'time')
 fig1 = px.line(df2, x = 'values', y = 'time')
 fig.show()
 fig1.show()
```

but every csv file is plotted individually i want them to be on the same plot.  like this plot

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Juip3.png]

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a unique dataframe with `df3=pd.concat([df,df2],axis=0)` and use it to create your plot.

If you want to distinguish your two tables in your plot. You can create a new columns in your dataframe:
`df["Frame"]="df"`
`df["Frame"]="df2"`
`df3=pd.concat([df,df2],axis=0)`

And add color option in `px.line`

`fig = px.line(df2, x = 'values', y = 'time',color='Frame')`

`fig.show()`

Comment: but i have 8 files, do i have to do it to all of them or there is another way ?

Comment: If you don't want to create each df separatly I think you can loop through a list of csv path, you import your df create a column "Frame" and concat each subframe into a "bigframe". I think it's still a better solution than handling 8 similar df independently

Answer (score 1):

- have synthesized CSV files to make MWE
- have presented two approaches

  1. concat all into one data frame then create figure
  2. create figure and add a trace for each CSV
- in both have used `glob()` to get all CSVs in a directory

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# setup env - define where your director is here:
# this is where you define youy directory.
# on my mac this is '/Users/fake/PycharmProjects/moviedb/jupyter/SO71123005'
f = Path.cwd().joinpath("SO71123005")
if not f.is_dir():
    f.mkdir()

# generate some CSVs for MWE - remove in real code...
for i in range(10):
    pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "time": pd.date_range("14-Feb-2022", freq="1H", periods=48),
            "values": np.random.uniform(1, 20, 48),
        }
    ).to_csv(f.joinpath(f"{i}.csv"), index=False)
# remove end

# create a line trace per CSV file in directory by concatenating all CSVs into data frame
px.line(
    pd.concat([pd.read_csv(csv).assign(file=csv.name) for csv in f.glob("*.csv")]),
    x="time",
    y="values",
    color="file",
).show()

# create a figure then add a line for each CSV in directory
fig = go.Figure()
for csv in f.glob("*.csv"):
    fig.add_traces(
        px.line(pd.read_csv(csv), x="time", y="values")
        .update_traces(line_color=None, showlegend=True, name=csv.name)
        .data
    )
fig
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer, i just have a ready csv files and a dir, with this code i did not know where i should my dir and my csv files ..sorry i am new to python

Comment: updated comments in code hopefully is clear now